# How to bulk change meta field value in WP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Created a catalog via CPT (NOT WooCommerce) and each product has a meta field (via ACF) - Price (price)
Please tell me how you can massively (for all products), change this meta field price (price) to the required percentage (for example, 15%)

Ideally, I need to set the required percentage on the settings page and, if this setting is saved, the meta field price (price) for all products in the catalog will change

I tried

```
function change_price( )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta SET meta_value = meta_value * 1.135 WHERE meta_key = 'price'");
}
```

But I dont understand how it work on settings page, on how "action"

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Bhautik I tried function change_price( )
 {
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->query("UPDATE " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta SET meta_value = meta_value * 1.135 WHERE meta_key = 'price'");
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code to your theme's functions.php file or a custom plugin.

The code will only execute the price update if this parameter is present and its value is set to `'true'`. This allows you to control when the price update should happen by appending `?update_prices=true` to the URL.

```
// Function to update the price meta field for a specific custom post type
function update_catalog_prices() {
    global $wpdb;
    
    // Check if the required parameter is present in the request
    if ( isset( $_GET['update_prices'] ) && $_GET['update_prices'] === 'true' ) {
        // Get the required percentage from the settings page
        $required_percentage = get_option('required_percentage');
        
        // Check if the required percentage is set
        if ($required_percentage) {
            // Define the custom post type to update
            $post_type = 'catalog';
            
            // Calculate the new price based on the required percentage
            $new_price = $required_percentage / 100;
            
            // Update the meta field 'price' for all products of the specified custom post type
            $wpdb->query(
                $wpdb->prepare(
                    "UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta SET meta_value = meta_value * %f WHERE meta_key = %s AND post_id IN (SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type = %s)",
                    $new_price,
                    'price',
                    $post_type
                )
            );
        }
    }
}

// Hook the function to an action to execute it
add_action('init', 'update_catalog_prices');
```

Please make sure to replace `'price'` with the actual meta key for the price field in your ACF setup.